# setting a view of dropbox in IOS 7 iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, dropbox, dropbox-api

I have integrate drop box API in my iPhone application. but when drop box view opens it will cut in ios 7.

it runs perfectly ios 6 but some part of view is hide under navigation bar in ios 7

how can i solve this issue? please help.!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you are using old SDK for drop box. please use new SDK from following link.

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/sync/sdks/ios

And follow Examples which are already provided in SDK

I hope it will work.